# C#, mssing some data from serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

I am using the following code to receive data from serial port, but the data I got some time miss som values, example when I send the ascii "123456" by Realterm program to the serial port, it should give me always:

```
buffer[0]:49
buffer[1]:50
buffer[2]:51
buffer[3]:52
buffer[4]:53
buffer[5]:54
```

But some time I get:

```
buffer[0]:51
buffer[1]:52
buffer[2]:53
buffer[3]:54
```

or:

```
buffer[0]:50
```

This is happen even when I send the data in very slow sequence?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmdClose.Enabled = false;
        foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            txtPort.Items.Add(s);
        }
        txtPort.SelectedItem = "COM5";
        cmbbaudrate.SelectedItem = "115200";
        cmbparity.SelectedItem = "None";
        cmbdatabits.SelectedItem = "8";
        cmbstopbits.SelectedItem = "One";
    }

    public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort SP;
    public void serialport_connect(String port, int baudrate, Parity parity, int databits, StopBits stopbits)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        SP = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);

        try
        {
            SP.Open();
            SP.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sport_DataReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error"); }
    }


    private void sport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[SP.BytesToRead];
        SP.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("buffer[" +i +"]:" +buffer[i]);
            txtReceive.AppendText("buffer[" + i + "]:" + buffer[i] +"\n");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the ReadExisting method.

> "The SerialPort class buffers data, but the stream object contained in
>   the SerialPort.BaseStream property does not. Therefore, the SerialPort
>   object and the stream object might differ on the number of bytes that
>   are available to read. When bytes are buffered to the SerialPort
>   object, the BytesToRead property includes these bytes in its value;
>   however, these bytes might not be accessible to the stream contained
>   in the BaseStream property"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helped a bit! :)